# Apache httpd, map war with version number to fixed url

Tags: apache, tomcat

I would like to deploy my war file, lets call it myapp-1.0.war, to tomcat 8, and be able to access the app with url `http://<hostname>/myapp`

I tried to achieve this by editing the webapps.conf in apache httpd 2.4 with the following content:

```
# Rewrite rule for URL without a trailing slash
<IfModule rewrite_module>
    RewriteRule     ^/myapp$        /myapp/     [R,L]
</IfModule>

Alias /myapp "E:/apache-tomcat-instances/instance01/webapps/myapp-1.0"
<Directory "E:/apache-tomcat-instances/instance01/webapps/myapp-1.0">
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule jk_module>
  JkMount  /myapp/* worker01
</IfModule>
```

However, this does not work. When I go to url `http://<hostname>/myapp`, I get redirected to `http://<hostname>/myapp/`, but I get a 404 in return.

Any hints of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the use of `mod_rewrite`, adjust your paths in `httpd.conf`, and use Tomcat's built-in versioning for WAR files:

`C:\> REN "E:/apache-tomcat-instances/instance01/webapps/myapp-1.0" "E:/apache-tomcat-instances/instance01/webapps/myapp##1.0"`

This also allows you to deploy a new version, say, `myapp##1.1` and have them both deployed at the same time. Users without a session will go to the newer version, and users with existing sessions will go to their assigned version.

Check out [Tomcat's documentation for parallel deployment](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html#Parallel_deployment).